# Extend a socket.onmessage = (e) => {} without overwriting its parent

Tags: javascript, sockets, web

How can you extend the following code

```
// socket.js
window['socket'] = new WebSocket('wss://wss.somedomain.com:1000');
socket.onmessage = (e) => {
    let payload = JSON.parse(e.data);
    if (payload.event === 'event1') {
        // do stuff here which works
    }
}

// otherFile.js
// extend the socket JS socket.onmessage = (e) => {}
socket.onmessage = (e) => {
    let payload = JSON.parse(e.data);
    if (payload.event === 'event1') {
        // do more stuff on event1
    }
}
```

How do I extend this socket.onmessage = (e) => {} without overwriting the one in socket.js

Answer (score 3):

You probably want `addEventListener` instead. `addEventListener` lets you attach multiple callbacks such that they don't cancel each other out:

```
// socket.js
window['socket'] = new WebSocket('wss://wss.somedomain.com:1000');
socket.addEventListener('message', (e) => {
    let payload = JSON.parse(e.data);
    if (payload.event === 'event1') {
        // do stuff here which works
    }
});

// otherFile.js
// extend the socket JS socket.onmessage = (e) => {}
socket.addEventListener('message', (e) => {
    let payload = JSON.parse(e.data);
    if (payload.event === 'event1') {
        // do more stuff on event1
    }
});
```

Answer (score -2):

You could store the original `socket.onmessage` in a variable then call that variable in your new `socket.onmessage` function:

```
// socket.js
window['socket'] = new WebSocket('wss://wss.somedomain.com:1000');
socket.onmessage = (e) => {
    let payload = JSON.parse(e.data);
    if (payload.event === 'event1') {
        // do stuff here which works
    }
}

// otherFile.js
// extend the socket JS socket.onmessage = (e) => {}
let oldSocketOnMessage = socket.onmessage;
socket.onmessage = (e) => {
    let payload = JSON.parse(e.data);
    if (payload.event === 'event1') {
        // do more stuff on event1
    }
    oldSocketOnMessage(e);  // call the original
}
```